# Is it possible to rollback mysql from 8.0.24 to 8.0.23?

Tags: mysql-8.0

I upgraded my dev server with mysql 8.0.24 but it doesn't work for me.  I keep getting a fatal crash every time a query uses GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT... and there are no rows because of the WHERE.  Anyway, I'd like to rollback to 8.0.23.  Was the file format upgraded?  Can I safely go back to 8.0.23?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, it's not easy to downgrade mysql.  Mysql itself says it's not possible:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html

I found some possible solution: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788395809/1/ch01lvl1sec18/downgrading-from-mysql-8-0

But in the end, I decided to revert the whole dev server to the last backup; that was easier, just a few clicks and back on my feet.